# Can adjectives be concrete in an ontological sense?

Tags: adjectives

*Hello everyone,*

*I'm trying to further define adjectives such as "beautiful" in an ontological sense.*

Can any adjectives which denote abstract OR concrete nouns, be concrete?

Can "beautiful" be an attribute, or is only "beauty" an attribute?

Is the ontology of adjectives dependent on their logic? (auto / hetero)

*I would be very thankful for help with this.*

Comment: Do you doubt _beautiful_ is an adjective?